# Convert linq model to generic list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, generics

I have an existing class Image which is used extensively throughout my application.
I need to return a generic list of images (List) to the frontend but as there is no stored proc in the 3ed party DB I am quering I need to use Linq to Sql.

I have create a dbtm file of the database I am quering in my DAL which looks like:

```
ImageCat
    ImageId
    Name
    Width
    DateModified
    Height
    CatId
```

My Image class is as follows

```
public class Image
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public int Width { get; set; }
 public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

My Linq to Sql is as follows:

```
var imageList = (from ic in db.ImageCats
   where ic.CatID.Contains(category)
 select ic).ToList();

var finalImageList = new List<Image>();
foreach (ImageCat ic in imageList)
{
 Image image = new Image();
 image.Id= ic.ImageID;
 image.Height = (int)ic.Height;
 image.Name = ic.Name;
 image.Width = (int)ic.Width;

 finalImageList.Add(image);   
}
```

I dont want to be looping through the linq to Sql result to setup my List. Is there an easier way. What is best practice? I dont like the idea of exposing my dbml classes to the presentation layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select directly to you `Image` class in the LINQ query

```
var imageList = (
    from ic in db.ImageCats
    where ic.CatID.Contains(category)
    select new Image()
    {
         Id= ic.ImageID,
         Height = (int)ic.Height,
         Name = ic.Name,
         Width = (int)ic.Width,
    }
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
var imageList = db.ImageCats.Where(ic => ic.CatID.Contains(category))
.Select(ic => new Image{ Id = ic.ImageID, 
                         Height = (int)ic.Height, 
                         Name = ic.Name, 
                         Width = (int)ic.Width})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Works OK, but you will be creating a bunch of temporary ImageCat objects along the way.

Answer (score -1):

```
IEnumerable<Image> = from ic in db.ImageCats
                     where ic.CatID.Contains(category)
                     select new Image() { Id= ic.ImageID, Height = (int)ic.Height, Name = ic.Name, Width = (int)ic.Width }.ToList();
```

I think something along those lines will give you an IEnumerable filled with Image objects.  I wrote that in the editing window so I could be way off though.  Try it out and let me know if it worked out for you.

Comment: There are roughly three errors preventing this code from compiling.

Comment: looking that over now, as well as looking at the selected answer I am seeing them.  I think some more might come up after fixing those too.  Sorry for the crappy code (as it was written in the editor), but the idea was sound :P